# Creating a Backup or Archive of a Marketing Cloud Account

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export

After an account migration what would be the best way to "download" and archive as much of the data as possible from an account before it gets shut down?

Would everything that can be extracted be available in a data extract activity? I can imagine that would cover most of the data available but wondering if anybody has had to "archive" an old account in the past and had any tips or advice on what can be extracted.

Comment: Are you talking about the 'customer' and/or tracking data or are you including 'account' data, as in admin info, as well?

Comment: @Gortonington just the customer and tracking data is my main concern but if there is an easy way to obtain account data I would get that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get all the raw customer data is via [Tracking Extracts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5).

This will give you pretty much everything related to emails that you have inside of each of your business units.

The issue is that there is that you can only go back a certain amount per extract, so you may need to run this multiple times to get all your records.

```
Attributes
The attributes tracking extract output file contains the attributes associated with subscribers in an account.

Bounces
The bounce event extract file shows all the hard and soft bounces occurring within a specified date range. The events in this report relate to all sends for subscribers on a list or related to a particular send.

ClickImpression
The click event extract file shows all the instances of a clicked link in an email occurring within the specified date range. The file also includes the impression region name associated with the click event. The events in this report can relate to all sends for subscribers on a list or related to a particular send.

Clicks
The click event extract file shows all instances of a clicked link in an email occurring within the specified date range. The events in this report relate to all sends for subscribers on a list or related to a particular send.

Conversions
The conversions file contains a row for each conversion event associated with a subscriber related to an email send job.

ListMembershipChanges
The ListMembershipChanges file includes rows that contain information on the subscriber, list, and status data change for every event.

Lists
The lists file contains rows including name, description, and other information for a unique list.

NotSent
This list contains information on send jobs and messages that did not send.

Opens
An Open event extract file shows open instances of an HTML email during the date range. The open events relate to all sends for subscribers on a list or to a particular send.

SendImpression
The SendImpression event extract file shows instances of an email send occurring during a specified date range. The file also includes the impression region name associated with the click event. The send events relate to all sends for subscribers on a list or to a particular send.

SendJobImpression
The SendJobImpression file represents all impression tracking information from sends with activity logged against them for the timeframe of the extract. This list reflects only jobs that already processed. Sends scheduled for the future do not appear in this list.

SendJobs
The SendJobs file represents all sends with activity logged against them for the timeframe of the extract. This list reflects only jobs that already processed. Sends scheduled for the future do not appear in this list.

Sent
The Sent event extract file shows instances of an email send occurring during a specified date range. The send events relate to all sends for subscribers on a list or to a particular send.

Spam Complaints
The Extract Spam Complaints extract file shows subscriber, list, and domain data, including sendID and date, for subscribers who received an email and reported it as spam.
StatusChanges
The StatusChanges file shows instances of change in a subscriber's status.

Subscribers
The Subscribers file contains subscribers with a tracking event occurring during a specified data range.

Surveys
The Surveys file contains information on responses to surveys included in email sends.

Unsubs
The Unsubs file includes information on unsubscriptions that occurred during a specified data range. The unsubscribe events can be related to all sends for subscribers on a list or to a particular send.
```